# Webscraping - List return empty

Tags: python-3.x, list, web-scraping, treeview

I currently try to scrap [this](https://www.renault-retail-group.fr/concessions-renault.html) page however my list return empty. I don't know if my tree map is wrong or if is it my loop... and of to modify it

My code :

```
url = "https://www.renault-retail-group.fr/concessions-renault.html"

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.maximize_window()

try:
driver.get(url)
except TimeoutError:
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")

time.sleep((randint(2, 3)))

r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "audColResultatConcessionAdresse ng-binding"})

dict_name_r = []

for item in g_data:
dict_name_r.append(item.contents[1].findAll("h6", {"class": "audColResultatConcessionNom ng-binding"}))

print(dict_name_r)
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are two major reasons, why this can happen. First, you could have used wrong classes, id or other identifiers, which are not existing. I guess, that this is not the case. 
The more common reason is, that the data you need is fetched and placed through runtime. As long as you are requesting it from a local script, some js stuff (and other things) are not executed.

A possible solution for this is [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as it is able to simulate a browser session. Just check it out.

Hope I could help you. Have a nice day.

Comment: I will try with Selenium - ty :)